# Quantum analog of mixing time correlation functions

Tags: correlation-functions, ergodicity

Classical ergodic theory predicts that in maximally chaotic systems correlation functions relax to the long time limit
\begin{equation}
\langle A(0) B(t)\rangle_0 \to_{t\to+\infty} \langle A\rangle_0 \langle B\rangle_\infty
\end{equation}
where $\langle \cdot\rangle_0$ denotes the average w.r.t. the initial distribution $\rho_0$ and $\rho_\infty = \lim_{t\to+\infty}\rho_t = \lim_{t\to+\infty}e^{-\mathcal L t}\rho_0$ denotes the time evolution of the initial density due to the Liouvillian $\mathcal L$. Is there a quantum analog of such mixing limit (for two-operators correlation functions)? Any book or reference discussing the quantum problem would be highly appreciated.